# Combine generic interfaces with two generic types into one type with only one generic type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

In my case I'm working with [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) from React but my question is a pure typescript issue.

Take following:

```js
export interface State<T> {
  values: T;
  someOtherProp: boolean;
}

export interface ActionOne<T, K extends keyof T> {
  type: "UPDATE_VALUE_ONE";
  payload: { name: K; value: T[K] };
}


export interface ActionTwo<T, K extends keyof T> {
  type: "UPDATE_VALUE_TWO";
  payload: { name: K; value: T[K] };
}
```

Now the two action interfaces are combined into a single union type:

```js
type ActionTypes<T, K extends keyof T> = ActionOne<T, K> | ActionTwo<T, K>
```

In the next step a function will use `ActionTypes` as the type of it's parameter:

```js
export const reducer = <T>(
  state: State<T>,
  action: ActionTypes<T> // This already breaks because the second generic type is missing
): State<T> =>
{ 
   switch (action.type) {
     case "UPDATE_VALUE_ONE":
      return {
        ...state,
        values: { ...state.values, [action.payload.name]: action.payload.value}
      };
     case "UPDATE_VALUE_ONE":
    // ...
  }
}
```

As you can see in the code's comment `ActionTypes<T>` is already breaking.
In my case I don't want the `reducer` function to worry about what type `K` of `ActionTypes<T, K>` is.

I know I could add `keyof T` to `action: ActionTypes<T, keyof T>` but ths would break the typechecking for this line:

```js
values: { ...state.values, [action.payload.name]: action.payload.value}
```

because the type of `[action.payload.name]` coulde be different from `action.payload.value`

Actually it would even be more ideal if `ActionType<T, K extends keyof T>` would only have one generic type (`T`).

If `ActionOne` and `ActionTwo` were returned by a functions instead of passing them direclty as objec t it work would by declaring the functions inline:

```js
type ActionTypes<T> =
 | (<T, K extends keyof T>() => ActionOne<T, K>)
 | (<T, K extends keyof T>() => ActionTwo<T, K>);`
```

**Question**

How can the information of a second generic type `K` of an interface be "hidden" when it is used in another interface/type that only declares one generic type `T`? (Especially if `K` is anyway dependend on `T` by `K extends keyof T`.)

For generic functions this can be solved through inline declaration, so how can it be solved for interfaces?

Comment: type ActionTypes<T> = IActionOne<T, keyof T> | IActionTwo<T, keyof T>;

Comment: as I already said in my post, this is not going to help because it will break typechecking..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it seems like you would like the `action` parameter to be the union of all possible action types... for each possible `K` in `keyof T`.  If so, I would use a [distributive conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#distributive-conditional-types) to break the union `keyof T` into each individual literal `K`, and get the union of all of `ActionTypes<T, K>`:

```
type SomeActionOne<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = K extends any
  ? ActionOne<T, K>
  : never;
type SomeActionTwo<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = K extends any
  ? ActionTwo<T, K>
  : never;
type AllPossibleActionTypes<T> = SomeActionOne<T> | SomeActionTwo<T>;
```

(UPDATE:  I modified the above version of `AllPossibleActionTypes<T>` to distribute over `ActionOne<T, K>` for all `K`, and then separately distribute `ActionTwo<T, K>` for all `K`, and then unify them afterwards.  Note that this is *exactly the same type* when you specify a concrete type `T`, but when `T` is still an unresolved generic the compiler reasons differently about them.  Specifically, in the old version, the compiler would wait until it knew `T` to split the types into `ActionOne` and `ActionTwo` varieties; now the compiler knows this from the start.)

Then the signature of `reducer` would be:

```
export const reducer = <T>(
  state: State<T>,
  action: AllPossibleActionTypes<T>
): State<T> => { ... }
```

And you could see that you are reasonably hinted when you call `reducer()`:

```
reducer(
  { values: { a: "a", b: 1, c: true }, someOtherProp: true },
  { type: "UPDATE_VALUE_TWO", payload: { name: "b", value: 3 } }
); // hinted for value: number when you type in "b" for name
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZRk1QB4AVAPjgG8AoOOAN0wBsBXYAZwC44yBuenE4QAtsADyMABZoAClAhheAIwgQWwTEkEBfWrVCRYiFGiy44AQWwwEEJBKTByAGjgBpOKFRIAJpxwANbAAJ4Q6HxUdAwwoWDAvABEAKpyACJWZACiAPoAalYAMil5EgBy2UmCDGCYoSwQmH681HBImOK8HvxMrBy8ZADaHgC6vaicMLxTUMgA5nC6egZG0PDIqBg4eDZ2DmQA7hBunt4gvgHBYRFRNEJxCclpmTkFxaW5ZADqEtVCdQaTRaNHanUSnl6zHYEOGYyWK1ojzw+DEwD29kczlOXh8wH8gRC4UiZDgAF5rsS7hTcRd8VdtKEhAB+ay2TFOFxkdweChCXjORhoQTIghojEHY4486XQk3Enkym3SiK2myuCMlls-ZII4nbmePkMAXAIVQEXxXYsFhyCCcTgIFSaCW6y2cchUCmo8QuzkeuAAHzFPvZkv1FEEhnA6zg2AcUzgUGAfjYuCgio9AAohFNiBDCHmPa4hDgdbwrNbbfbHc7Q66Eu7KLQAJS8AukFVk6I5w4IGDYaRwTOlzEAOmRzfuDAY2EwnDwqQyWTyhRKZUqSW4QmnieAMDYUCQU5309HZ9zqGLJ+n0I4PFBZ9HF+Ao9vXHcQxHDlHgMazVHHTiKMvBfkgP71H+fivv0eD6NeyzbrGc4Li8y7vGuuQVFUW47gA9LhcCPkIcG7vuh7tGw1oAIR6JGSYpmm2YMG0b73m0mDJJgSTuCovAAIzuNgvAwFAHBLO4IjiFIshQAoSjCaJsFXqCyLPEubyrp8Px-O4v7Aq0YJdHASQqNxfQwrwADMSxLC2ka0EAA)

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer! Unfortunatly this is not working as soon as `ActionOne` and `ActionTwo` have different structures e.g. add a new property to `ActionOne`'s payload:
`payload: { name: K; value: T[K], test: string };`. In the `reducer()` the `action.test` property in case *UPDATE_VALUE_ONE* will not exsist. So yes, for the exact example that have given you it works, but sadly not in general ...

Comment: I didn't anticipate a generalization in that direction, sorry.  I will edit my answer to work for that case.

Comment: sorry for the late response.. I just tried it out and it's working as desired, thanks! Still it seems to be a bit messy because you have to declare a new `type` for each action that is dependent on `K` (in my case it's more than just two actions..) I'm really wondering if there is no better alternative